# Compare reliability / lifetimes/ failures of two different groups

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, survival, reliability, failure-rate

I have two different groups of devices with different failure rates:

- ***Group 1***: 72 devices, 57 % did not fail during observation.
- ***Group 2***: 11 devices, no device failed during observation.

How could I determine whether these groups resp. their reliability, lifetime or the like is different from each other?
My ad-hoc approach would be to calculate the group-related lifetime and to use a certain statistical test whether there is a difference in the mean values (have to figure out which test exactly). Is this reasonable and/or is there a different/better method to proceed?

Comment: Were the durations of observation identical for the two groups? If cases in Group 2 were observed for shorter durations than were those in Group 1, you can't make any reliable conclusions from this type of data without further information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the question we can see only see three pieces of information: group allocation, number of observations and failures within each group.

Knowing that, you could simply run a simple Chi square test for independence or, because you only have two groups and two "outcomes" (failed and not failed) you can use the Mantel Haenszel test as well.

If you have the information on the time until failure (lifetime), you could use a Logrank test, which compares the distributions of the survival times. This is a specific case of the Mantel Haenszel test in which you use time stratification ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logrank_test)).

Regarding "reliability", there is such a term in statistics, but probably you are interested in having more insights on the survival distribution. I recommend having a look at Kaplan-Meier curves by group ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan%E2%80%93Meier_estimator)).

If you have more data you want to add for the comparison of the two groups (for instance multiple secondary grouping variables), you might want to look into regression models, opting for the Cox Proportional Hazard or the Accelerated Failure Time model. However, the choice between the two depends on your problem, but I don't think you need them from what you described so far.

All the above statistical tools are implemented in any software and usually well described.

Personally, I recommend Logrank and Kaplan-Meier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very useful input! I would like to question them a bit: For the chi square test I need more/individual data of each device, or? For the other test I found a test in r which is called Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel test, is it the same? Next regarding survival analysis which I also prefer (I guess I'll get individual data in the future) but how do I determine whether the curves are different? Simply when they are different from each other or would I pull some values from the analysis and explore further?

Comment: Lastly, I haven't done accelerated failure time model but from the purpose and the experiment itself this would also make sense. Could you please tell me shortly how it is different from survival analysis?

Comment: 1) You can use the classic Exact Chi-square test with the data you have, but it does not take in account the time. 2) the Logrank test is version of the Cochran-M-H test where time is used as stratification variable, but I recommend you stick to sources that call it Logrank to make things easier. I share this tutorial for R software in which you can plan Kaplan-Meier curves and Logrank pvalue in the same graph ([here](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/survminer/)).

Comment: 3) The Logrank exactly tests for each survival time the difference between the two groups, using a similar interpretation to the M-H test. 4) You can do whatever you prefer, but I recommend visual inspection of the K-M curves before anything. I am not sure what you mean by "pull out some values". 5) The AFT model is part of survival analysis tool kit. Cox and AFT are different in terms of how you interpret the effect of the covariates on the survival time.

Comment: I like this paper to see a bit of the difference between Cox and AFT ([here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/974/1/012008))

Comment: This ([here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/226159159.pdf)) for an even more detailed description.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your input!

Comment: Hi, I noticed that, at least in r, it seems that the manteltest() can only be run with >=3 nominal variables? So I would need to run the chi square test, right (when not taking into account time)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147615/discussion-between-jmarkov-and-ben).